# In JSX | React How can the prop be passed to the button state so the button state can load a new page?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to go from the search using the react datepicker and then check available dates. Having some trouble passing the props to the btn so I can create the new page based on the date selected.

Everything is Imported correctly we can leave that out below is my Datapicker Component and the Btnsearch Component I need the pops to be used by.

I have tried to pass the prop in every element on the component, with the btn built in to the component. I have read its better to pass the props down the chain of elements. To children so I tried to do that lastly. Still can't seem to catch the Datepicked to even console.log it.Tried to build a alert as well.

```
class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  state = {};
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.value);
    return (
      <>
        <FormGroup>
          <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
              <InputGroupText
              >
                <i className="ni ni-calendar-grid-58" />
              </InputGroupText>
            </InputGroupAddon>
            <ReactDatetime
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              placeholder: "Date Picker Here"
            }}
            timeFormat={false}
            />
          </InputGroup>
        </FormGroup>
        <Btnsearch />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

```
class Btnsearch extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <button value={this.props.value} className="btn btn-success search-card-btn">Search</button>
    );
    }
};

export default Btnsearch;
```

I expect to console.log and alert the props been changed when the button is clicked in order to populate a new page. I get props undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass down the prop:

```
 <Btnsearch value={this.state.value}/>
```

Otherwise your component would never get it.

**Edit:** there was several issues in your code, I made a snippet for you to check.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-af37vl

Select a date, hit "search" and date will be logged in console.

Notice (from react-datetime docs):

> Callback trigger when the date changes. The callback receives the
>   selected moment object as only parameter, if the date in the input is
>   valid. If the date in the input is not valid, the callback receives
>   the value of the input (a string).

Comment: Sure this is a valid point, but that doesn't fix the fact that the Prop wont even get console.loged

Comment: _×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Datepicker.handleChange
src/components/Toolbar/SearchCard/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx:28_

Comment: You are setting it in state, not getting it in props, mate. You can get props only from parent component.

Comment: Then can you show me how to do it correctly? I mean I'm kinda really lost on that I need to to be passed so I can use the date selected to go to the next phase of the booking process

Comment: I tried something like ` this.state = {
      value: "{this.props.value}"
    };`

Comment: Never, NEVER mutate directly the state, mate. Use always setState()

Comment: Changed my code to your code and still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Datepicker.handleChange
src/components/Toolbar/SearchCard/Datepicker/Datepicker.jsx:28`

Comment: This is being done in a search card parent component should I care that as well?

Comment: All the search card really is, is the background

Comment: Check my code where I set the state. event.target.value does does not exists, as the argument passed is a moment date.

Comment: I checked your code its not working for me in my code.

Comment: Also the other factor that is mission is that this only console logs this does not alert as well. So this is only a partial answer

Comment: May be you have other issues in your code, there is a deep misunderstanding of how javascript and react works. The code is correct and if you replace my console.log with an alert it will work too. If you need further help, please post a working snippet reproducing your issue.

Comment: Note: no JSX element calls your handlesubmit method, that's the reason it is not fired.